# how to get foursquare ID through foursquare api?

Tags: foursquare

i integrate foursquare api in my app. and when i use method **findLocationsNearbyLatitude**
i get id of venues but not is foursquare id. please tell me how to get foursquare ID of location through foursquare API? thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

Call this method passing in the lat and longitude 
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html

this will then return a compact array of venues 
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue.html

This will then provide the foursquare id of each venue for you to use